# e.OldElement and e.NewElement in custom renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view) Microsoft tells us to use `e.OldElement` and `e.NewElement` in custom renderers:

> ...to prevent memory leaks, care must be taken when instantiating a new
>   native control...
>
> ...
>
> ```
>   if (e.OldElement != null) {
>     // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
>   }
>
>   if (e.NewElement != null) {
>     // Configure the control and subscribe to event handlers
>   }
> ```

On the other hand [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry) they ignore their own recommendation:

> ```
>     if (Control != null) {
>         // do whatever you want to the UITextField here!
>         Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB (204, 153, 255);
>         Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line;
>     }
> ```

So do we or do we not need to worry about them? Or does it depend on the case (and therefore: where is which?)?

Comment: Only if your control is subscribing to events/event handlers do you need to worry about unsubscribing from them otherwise you can just set whatever properties like in the second code snippet.