# Difference between e.NewElement and Control?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So when making a custom renderer , you do most of your work inside the overriden OnElementChanged() function.I want to make a custom renderer for the Xamarin.Forms.Picker control:

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
```

what is here the difference between e.NewElement and Control?The second one seems to be inherited from ViewRenderer(PickerRenderer in my case).I also don't quite understand what e.OldElement does, maybe the reference to my last custom Picker? Thanks.

Comment: Might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064694/e-oldelement-and-e-newelement-in-custom-renderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Control` (`this.Control`) is the PLATFORM control. E.g. on Android, it is a subclass of `Android.Views.View`.
- `Element` (`this.Element`) refers to the XAMARIN FORMS cross-platform element/view. It is a subclass of `Xamarin.Forms.View`.
- `e.NewElement` is always identical to `this.Element`.
- `e.OldElement` is the previous value that was attached to this custom renderer. It will be `null` when the renderer is created.
- When the renderer is disposed, `OnElementChanged` might be called again, with `e.OldElement` being the XF element that is going away. In this case, `e.NewElement` is `null`.

IMPORTANT: In `OnElementChanged`, **always check whether `e.NewElement` is `null`.** If it is, do nothing. (Or call any "cleanup" code, if you need to do something when "going away"/disposing.)

Comment: But if OnElementChanged gets fired when a custom view with that custom renderer is created, how can e.NewElement ever be null?

Comment: See last bullet point: *"When the renderer is disposed, OnElementChanged might be called again, ... In this case, e.NewElement is null"*